# Get rid of Extra space Table

Tags: tables

Any suggestions to get rid of the EXTRA space table latex?

here the code and my output :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
    \usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsthm} 
    \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
   \usepackage{mathpazo}
   \usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}
  \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
  \usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf},tableposition=top]{caption}
 \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
 \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xparse}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage[title]{appendix}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \caption{Contribution to volatility and levels of endogenous variables}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}r}
  \hline
  Variable  & Horizon &Decomposition of volatility shocks & Decomposition of level shocks \\
 \hline
 \hline
GNP growth (y) & 2 Q& 34.819 & 22.206  \\
 && \textit{(23.5,28.40)}&\textit{(23.2,24.2)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  4 Q&23.901& 18.167\\
 && \textit{(15.52,18.65)}&\textit{(11.37,12.51)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 17.684&14.316 \\
 && \textit{(10.48,12.58)}&\textit{(8.57,9.52)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 9.654& 6.18\\
 && \textit{(2.08,2.48)}&\textit{(1.07,2.42)}\\
 \hline
 Unemployment (U) &2 Q & 8.874 & 6.245  \\
 && \textit{(9.52,12.44)}&\textit{(8.32,9.62)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  4 Q& 10.658 & 9.265  \\
 && \textit{(7.08,8.46)}&\textit{(6.82,7.22)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 8.840 & 6.235  \\
 && \textit{(6.32,7.02)}&\textit{(5.72,6.02)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 4.902 & 3.245  \\
&& \textit{(2.74,4.40)}&\textit{(1.40,3.10)}\\
\hline
Inflation (P) &2 Q & 34.736& 29.425  \\
&& \textit{(13.64,14.20)}&\textit{(12.12,13.14)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  4 Q& 27.405 & 26.278  \\
&& \textit{(13.02,12.65)}&\textit{(11.02,11.40)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 22.632 & 20.279  \\
&& \textit{(1.79,11.89)}&\textit{(1.62,11.72)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 17.893 & 15.719  \\
  && \textit{(10.24,0.40)}&\textit{(10.12,0.19)}\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
  \label{tab4}
   \begin{tablenotes}{\textwidth}
   \small
   \item Note:This table reports the changes in forecast error variances by level shocks and 
   volatility shock
    using the VAR model with time-varying stochastic volatility.
   \end{tablenotes}  
   \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** working example ([see here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)). Also, where exactly is the space you want removed?

Comment: Do not load packages more than once. You will recieve error messages about clashing options for several packages if you try to compile your current example. (e.g. `eucal`, `geometry`, `caption`...) Please clean up the preamble accordingly. Also, please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Which "extra space"  do you want to remove? Do you want to make columns 3 and 4 narrower? Please also clarify how wide your table notes should be. As wide as the table itself or as wide as the textwidth?

Comment: It looks like you're loading the `caption` package six [6!!] times. Several other packages, too numerous to mention individually, are loaded two or more times. E.g., what's with loading `geometry` and `mathtools` three times? Some of them are loaded with *mutually incompatible* options (e.g., the `inputenc` package). The effects of some packages (e.g., `mathpazo`) get overwritten entirely when you load conflicting packages (e.g., `lmodern`). Before you tackle the "look" of the table, you may want to clean up the preamble.

Comment: @leandriis between third and fourth column

Comment: @haithem: Do you still want to keep the contents of the two columns horizontally centered? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis YES but keeping also  2Q, 4Q, 8Q,12Q  centered

Comment: Add a linebreak inside of the column headers of column 3 and 4. If you split the text into two lines, the columns get narrower automatically and you can remove duplicate information.

Comment: Why do you declare 6 columns? You actually only need 4 for this specific table.

Comment: @leandriis  Yes I see the issue but I still don't get a Nice Looking Table :(

Comment: @haithem: Regarding "still don't get": Which changes exactly did you do to your code and which output do you get? Did you already addess the preamble issues?

Comment: @leandriis I deleted packages that may be conflicting or duplicated but I still don't get what you mean by including // in the third and fourth column, do you mean by including  \thead{Decomposition of \\ volatility shocks} ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Do please clean up the preamble thoroughly. Absolutely nothing good can come from such a conflicted mess. Sorry to have to use such harsh words, but there's simply no adequate euphemism that might cover up the situation.
- To make the table take up less horizontal space, you *must* allow line breaks in the long header cells of columns 3 and 4. You can do this either manually or with the help of the `tabularx` environment and the `X` column type. In the code below, I've chosen the `tabularx` route, setting the overall width to `0.8\textwidth`.
- I'd use `\mathit` rather than `\textit`. That way, the parentheses will get rendered in upright shape and TeX will insert a bit of whitespace after the commas.
- You're not using the machinery of the `threeparttable` package correctly. Indeed, your use of a `tablenotes` environment accomplishes nothing at all except to create code clutter. I suggest doing away with the `tablenotes` wrapper and using a `threeparttable` environment to encase the caption, the `tabularx` environment, and the subsequent notes. That way, width of the notes will be constrained to the width of the `tabularx` environment.
- I would do away with the `\hline` and `\cline` instructions and, in their stead, employ the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % or: \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp} % are you sure you need this package?
\usepackage{cuted}    % ditto
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % ditto
\usepackage[font={small,bf},
            labelfont={bf,sf},
            tableposition=top,
            justification=centering,
            figurename=Fig.,
            skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{empheq}         % ditto
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}      % ditto   
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}
% centered version of 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, threeparttable}
\usepackage{xparse,xstring} % ditto
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage{varioref}  
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Contribution to volatility and levels of endogenous variables}
\label{tab4}
 
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{@{} l c C C @{}}
\toprule
Variable 
   & Horizon 
   & Decomposition of volatility shocks 
   & Decomposition of level shocks \\
\midrule
GNP growth (\,$y$) 
   &  2 Q& 34.819 & 22.206  \\
   && $\mathit{(23.5,28.40)}$ & $\mathit{(23.2,24.2)}$\\
   &  4 Q& 23.901& 18.167\\
   && $\mathit{(15.52,18.65)}$ & $\mathit{(11.37,12.51)}$\\
   &  8 Q& 17.684&14.316 \\
   && $\mathit{(10.48,12.58)}$ & $\mathit{(8.57,9.52)}$\\
   &  12 Q& 9.654& 6.18\\
   && $\mathit{(2.08,2.48)}$ & $\mathit{(1.07,2.42)}$\\
\addlinespace
Unemployment ($U$)  
   &  2 Q& 8.874 & 6.245  \\
   && $\mathit{(9.52,12.44)}$ & $\mathit{(8.32,9.62)}$\\
   &  4 Q& 10.658 & 9.265  \\
   && $\mathit{(7.08,8.46)}$ & $\mathit{(6.82,7.22)}$\\
   &  8 Q& 8.840 & 6.235  \\
   && $\mathit{(6.32,7.02)}$ & $\mathit{(5.72,6.02)}$\\
   &  12 Q& 4.902 & 3.245  \\
   && $\mathit{(2.74,4.40)}$ & $\mathit{(1.40,3.10)}$\\
\addlinespace
Inflation ($P$) 
   &  2 Q& 34.736& 29.425  \\
   && $\mathit{(13.64,14.20)}$ & $\mathit{(12.12,13.14)}$\\
   &  4 Q& 27.405 & 26.278  \\
   && $\mathit{(13.02,12.65)}$ & $\mathit{(11.02,11.40)}$\\
   &  8 Q& 22.632 & 20.279  \\
   && $\mathit{(1.79,11.89)}$ & $\mathit{(1.62,11.72)}$\\
   &  12 Q& 17.893 & 15.719  \\
   && $\mathit{(10.24,0.40)}$ & $\mathit{(10.12,0.19)}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  
\medskip
Note: This table reports the changes in forecast error 
variances by level and volatility shocks, using 
the VAR model with time-varying stochastic volatility.

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback, this is what I'm looking for. I believe your answer is better

Answer (score 4):

I will not comment on the packages issues, review the comments by other people above. For the extra width of columns, you can use `\makecell{}` to split the cell into two rows.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
 \caption{Contribution to volatility and levels of endogenous variables}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
  \hline
  Variable  & Horizon & \makecell{Decomposition of\\volatility shocks} & \makecell{Decomposition of\\level shocks} \\
 \hline
 \hline
GNP growth (y) & 2 Q& 34.819 & 22.206  \\
 && \textit{(23.5,28.40)}&\textit{(23.2,24.2)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  4 Q&23.901& 18.167\\
 && \textit{(15.52,18.65)}&\textit{(11.37,12.51)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 17.684&14.316 \\
 && \textit{(10.48,12.58)}&\textit{(8.57,9.52)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 9.654& 6.18\\
 && \textit{(2.08,2.48)}&\textit{(1.07,2.42)}\\
 \hline
 Unemployment (U) &2 Q & 8.874 & 6.245  \\
 && \textit{(9.52,12.44)}&\textit{(8.32,9.62)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  4 Q& 10.658 & 9.265  \\
 && \textit{(7.08,8.46)}&\textit{(6.82,7.22)}\\
 \cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 8.840 & 6.235  \\
 && \textit{(6.32,7.02)}&\textit{(5.72,6.02)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 4.902 & 3.245  \\
&& \textit{(2.74,4.40)}&\textit{(1.40,3.10)}\\
\hline
Inflation (P) &2 Q & 34.736& 29.425  \\
&& \textit{(13.64,14.20)}&\textit{(12.12,13.14)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  4 Q& 27.405 & 26.278  \\
&& \textit{(13.02,12.65)}&\textit{(11.02,11.40)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  8 Q& 22.632 & 20.279  \\
&& \textit{(1.79,11.89)}&\textit{(1.62,11.72)}\\
\cline{2-4} &  12 Q& 17.893 & 15.719  \\
  && \textit{(10.24,0.40)}&\textit{(10.12,0.19)}\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
  \label{tab4}
   \begin{tablenotes}{\textwidth}
   \small
   \item Note:This table reports the changes in forecast error variances by level shocks and 
   volatility shock
    using the VAR model with time-varying stochastic volatility.
   \end{tablenotes}  
   \end{table}
```

[image]